# wp members plugin login error message fix

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I have installed the `wp members`  plugin. I have created the page in admin. I used the following short code here

```
Login:::[wpmem_form login]

Register:: [wpmem_form register]
```

By using this the login form and registration forms are displayed correctly. If I give invalid login details to the login form, then it shows the error message in both login and registration forms. and the both forms are dis appeared. So two error messages are displayed in that area of login section and registration section.

How to fix this?

Comment: in single page you gave both short code?

Comment: @Anant: Yes I used both short codes in a single page.

Comment: Nope:- create two different pages. And in login create a link for registration page and in registration page create a link for login page. I did in the same way. I got the same problem also

Comment: @Anant: No I need the design like this (Client's requirement). Is any other way to fix this?